# Failed building wheel for trm.pgplot

Tags: python, pip

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6 and getting the following error while installing the package:

I am trying normal pip installation:

```
pip3 install . --user
```

and getting the following error message:

> Processing /home/chinmay/trm-pgplot
> Building wheels for collected packages: trm.pgplot
> Running setup.py bdist_wheel for trm.pgplot ... error
> Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-b_8sag87-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
> 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
> '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d
> /tmp/tmp6x5jsk6hpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running build_py
> package init file 'trm/**init**.py' not found (or not a regular file)
> creating build
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/trm
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/trm/pgplot
> copying trm/pgplot/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/trm/pgplot
> running build_ext
> building 'trm.pgplot._pgplot' extension
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/trm
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/trm/pgplot
> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DMAJOR_VERSION=0 -DMINOR_VERSION=1 -I/home/chinmay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/pgplot/ -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c trm/pgplot/_pgplot.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/trm/pgplot/_pgplot.o
> In file included from /home/chinmay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:0,
> from /home/chinmay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
> from /home/chinmay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
> from trm/pgplot/_pgplot.c:791:
> /home/chinmay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2:
> warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "
> "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
> #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " 
> ^~~~~~~
> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/trm/pgplot/_pgplot.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib
> -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/pgplot/ -lcpgplot -lpgplot -lX11 -lm -lgfortran -lpng -lz -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/trm/pgplot/_pgplot.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/pgplot//libpgplot.a(xwdriv.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not
> be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
> /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

try this: apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev

then try this: pip3 install Pillow (it worked for me)

also try updating the setup tools by: sudo pip install -U setuptools

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need c++ compiler

```
sudo apt install g++
```